# Is it safe in general to use spaces between specific thickness values (e.g. Margin or Padding) in XAML elements?

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamarin, uwp, conventions

Recently one of my colleagues started using spaces instead of commas as separators for specific values in Thickness fields like Margin and Padding:

```xml
<Label Margin="0 1 2 3"/>
```

While previously we used commas:

```xml
<Label Margin="0,1,2,3"/>
```

He says he saw a lot of usage of this style in XAML examples across the web, but could not provide any of them quickly. His code is working in .NET 6 project with WPF, but we have another projects with different .NET targets so I started digging if this style is acceptable is general.

[Some parts of WPF documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.block.margin?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#xaml-values:%7E:text=The%20four%20values%20must%20be%20separated%20with%20commas%3B%20spaces%20are%20not%20allowed) restrict usage to commas only:

> The four values must be separated with commas; spaces are not allowed.

[General article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.thickness?view=netframework-4.8) about Thickness in WPF does not mention separators at all (as for .NET Framework 4.8 and above), but provides an example with a starting whitespace, so I assume it is is OK:

```xml
<object property=" left,top,right,bottom" ... />
```

[Xamarin docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/margin-and-padding#specifying-a-thickness:%7E:text=%3CLabel%20Text%3D%22Xamarin.Android%22%20Margin%3D%220%2C%2020%2C%2015%2C%205%22%20/%3E) includes an example with both commas and spaces:

```xml
<Label Text="Xamarin.Android" Margin="0, 20, 15, 5" />
```

Although [similar article for MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/align-position#:%7E:text=%3CLabel%20Text%3D%22.NET%20Android%22%20Margin%3D%220%2C20%2C15%2C5%22%20/%3E) suggests an example without spaces and does not mention them:

```xml
 <Label Text=".NET Android" Margin="0,20,15,5" />
```

Finally [UWP docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.thickness?view=winrt-22621#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20a%20space%20rather%20than%20a%20comma%20as%20the%20delimiter%20between%20values.) explicitely says that commas and spaces are allowed to use, and one user even created an [issue for WinUI3](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/3710) when caught a problem with spaces.

So,

- Is it safe to use spaces in XAML in general (i.e. use it by default for projects targeting any .NET version or framework)?
- Is it allowed to mix them (like it was suggested by Xamarin example)? Will any preview engine (like in VS or JetBrains Rider) parse them correctly?
- *(That is a matter of opinion, but I still want to ask)* What style is considered the most readable and/or convinient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created all the differents project you mentioned. I found that:

1. In the xamarin of the maui project, you must use the `,` to separate the values. If you use the space, it will throw the error (can't convert value `"1 1 1 1"` to Thickness).
2. In the WPF and the WinUI project, you can use the both `,` and space to separate the values.

In addition, if you both have `,` and space in the values, the space seems will be ignored. So I suggest you use the `,` to do that. Because the constructor of the Thickness class also used the `,`. Such as `new Thickness(left,top,right,bottom)`;